# Fix function argument data type as dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

Let say I have a function

```
def func(data:str):  
   pass
```

what I intend to make is to make sure it accepts dataframe as well along with string. How can I do it? I mean if a string is passed it should accept and if dataframe is passed, it also accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import typing
import pandas as pd
def func(data:typing.Union[str, pd.DataFrame]):  
   pass
```

or, if you use `python 3.10` or newer:

```
def func(data:str | pd.DataFrame):  
   print(type(data))
```

for more information and future reader:

this is `type-hinting` and does not do anything about accept or deny any `type` even if you specify only one `type`. for more strictness and that the function can't accpet any other `type`s, you must use `raise`:

```
def func(data):  
    if type(data) not in [str, pd.DataFrame]:
        raise RuntimeError("This is not good")
```

even this lenient let you to use `string`s as type-hinting, for example:

```
def func(data: "str"):  
    print(data)
```

and, also as you can see in first example, you can use any `class` for type-hinting, and this is a good practice.